# Android SQLite table column not being created or recognized. What am I missing?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am setting up an sqlite database that will store information about products. When it is time for a new item to be added to the database. I get errors for the first table column saying that no such table column exists, when I'm convinced it should be there. My hinch at the moment is that the problem lies in onCreate(). I'm new to sqlite and working on this for someone else, please excuse me if I've overlooked something elementary.

```
public class itemDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    /**Information*/
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ProductInfoDB";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "ProductInfo_Table";
    public static final String COL_PRODUCTNAME = "ProductName";
    public static final String COL_INITIALPRICE = "InitialPrice";
    public static final String COL_CURRENTPRICE = "CurrentPrice";
    public static final String COL_PRICECHANGE = "PriceChange";
    public static final String COL_ITEMWEBPAGE = "ItemWebPage";

    /** Constructor */
    public itemDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**Creates the table
     * @param db Takes the database and creates a table on it
     * */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String table =("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                + COL_PRODUCTNAME  +  " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + COL_INITIALPRICE +  " REAL,"
                + COL_CURRENTPRICE +  " REAL,"
                + COL_PRICECHANGE  +  " REAL,"
                + COL_ITEMWEBPAGE  +  " TEXT " + ") ");
        db.execSQL(table);
    }
    /**needed for database
     * Checks if table exists or not
     * */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    /** This method adds items to the table of the database
     * @param item, takes an item and gets its info, then places it on the table of the database
     * */
    public void addItem(Item item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_PRODUCTNAME,item.getName());
        contentValues.put(COL_INITIALPRICE,item.getPriceInitial());
        contentValues.put(COL_CURRENTPRICE,item.getPriceCurrent());
        contentValues.put(COL_PRICECHANGE,item.getPriceChange());
        contentValues.put(COL_ITEMWEBPAGE,item.getUrl());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
        db.close();
    }
    /** Methods aids in updating items on database
     * */
    public void updateItem(String oldName, Item item){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(COL_PRODUCTNAME,item.getName());
        values.put(COL_INITIALPRICE,item.getPriceInitial());
        values.put(COL_CURRENTPRICE,item.getPriceCurrent());
        values.put(COL_PRICECHANGE,item.getPriceChange());
        values.put(COL_ITEMWEBPAGE,item.getUrl());

        db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COL_PRODUCTNAME + " = ?", new String[]{oldName});
        db.close();

    }
    /** This method returns all the items found on the table of the database,
     * recurses the table and returns a list of items
     * */
    public List<Item> getAllItems() {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String itemName = cursor.getString(0);
                    double initialP = cursor.getDouble( 1);
                    double currentP = cursor.getDouble(2);
                    double priceC = cursor.getDouble(3);
                    String itemUrl = cursor.getString(4);

                    Item holder = new Item(itemName, initialP, currentP, priceC, itemUrl);
                    items.add(holder);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Here are the errors I get

```
2019-04-19 14:14:55.490 11936-11936/edu.package E/SQLiteLog: (1) table ProductInfo_Table has no column named ProductName
2019-04-19 14:14:55.500 11936-11936/edu.packageE/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting ProductName=tjastjtjjta PriceChange=0.0 CurrentPrice=1372.0450878788292 InitialPrice=1372.0450878788292 ItemWebPage=tuarhwrqhh
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table ProductInfo_Table has no column named ProductName (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO ProductInfo_Table(ProductName,PriceChange,CurrentPrice,InitialPrice,ItemWebPage) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:895)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:506)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1580)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1453)
        at edu.utep.cs.cs4330.homework3.itemDB.addItem(itemDB.java:68)
        at edu.utep.cs.cs4330.homework3.MainActivity.addItem(MainActivity.java:262)
        at edu.utep.cs.cs4330.homework3.EntryDialog$1.onClick(EntryDialog.java:66)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:164)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6313)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: You probably made changes to the names of the columns. Uninstall the app from the device and rerun to recreate the table.

Comment: @forpas It still gives the same error

Comment: Can you try incrementing the database version to see if that helps?

Comment: Check the manifest. Do you have this attribute: `android:allowBackup="true"`?

Comment: @forpas Yes its already there.

Comment: @the-dagger For some reason that worked. Why would that have made a difference?

Comment: Change that attribute to `false`.

Comment: @PizzaReceptacle upgrading the version tells the SQLite open helper that the database schema has changed; which causes the open helper to run migrations.

Since you don't have any migrations specified, it deletes the existing database and creates it again.

My guess is that originally you didn't have the `COL_PRODUCTNAME` entry in your table and it was added later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is any issue with the code you have supplied.

That is copying your code and using the following in the MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    itemDB ItemDBHlpr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ItemDBHlpr = new itemDB(this);
        Item myItem = new Item("tjastjtjjta",0.0,1372.0450878788292,1372.0450878788292,"tuarhwrqhh");
        ItemDBHlpr.addItem(myItem);
        List<Item> myItemList = ItemDBHlpr.getAllItems();
        for (Item i: myItemList) {
            Log.d("ITEMFROMLIST",
                    "Item Name is " + i.getName() +
                            "\n\tInitial Price = " + String.valueOf(i.getPriceInitial()) +
                            "\n\tCurrent Price = " + String.valueOf(i.getPriceCurrent()) +
                            "\n\tPrice Change = " + String.valueOf(i.getPriceChange()) +
                            "]n]tURL = " + i.getUrl()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Results in the following (as expected) in the log :-

```
04-20 07:21:16.291 10005-10005/? D/ITEMFROMLIST: Item Name is tjastjtjjta
        Initial Price = 0.0
        Current Price = 1372.0450878788292
        Price Change = 1372.0450878788292]n]tURL = tuarhwrqhh
```

## The Likely Issue

As such the issue is most likely that the App has been run and then changes were made that added the **ProductName** to the table's definition BUT the database wasn't deleted (achieved by either uninstalling the App, deleting the App's data or in your case increasing the Database Version (drops the table and recreates the table)).

The reason why deleting the database works is that the **onCreate** method only automatically runs when the database is created.

Increasing the Database Version number results in the **onUpgrade** method being called. This deletes and then recreates the table.

## Another Cause

Should a device being used for development have a working/enabled backup manager and the App's manifest has `android:allowBackup="true"`, then there is the potential that the App's data can be restored thus effectively negating uninstalling the App or clearing the App's data. Changing the manifest to use `android:allowBackup="false"` can overcome such issues.

In this case, increasing the Database Version will also work as it doesn't rely upon the database being deleted. Rather it works as the **onUpgrade** method is called, this DROP's the table and the call the **onCreate** method.

- Note this does rely upon the **onUpgrade** being coded accordingly (in this question it is).

## Additional

I'd also suggest a few changes to the **getAllItems** method (comments explain) to be something like :-

```
/** This method returns all the items found on the table of the database,
 * recurses the table and returns a list of items
 * */
public List<Item> getAllItems() {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME; //<<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT not needed as query method builds the SQL
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Generally recommended to use the query Convenience method rate than rawQuery
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    // No Need to do multiple checks for the same i.e. moveTo will return false if the move cannot be made
    //  if no rows then moveToNext returns false so loop ended
    //  if at last row then moveToNext will return false thus loop ended
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Rather than hard coding offsets (which could change over time)
                // better to get the offset according to the column name
                String itemName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PRODUCTNAME));
                double initialP = cursor.getDouble( cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_INITIALPRICE));
                double currentP = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_CURRENTPRICE));
                double priceC = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PRICECHANGE));
                String itemUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ITEMWEBPAGE));
                //Item holder = new Item(itemName, initialP, currentP, priceC, itemUrl); // No need for intermediate Item
                items.add(new Item(itemName, initialP, currentP, priceC, itemUrl)); //<<<<<<<<<< CHANGED
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation Mike! I was thinking of something like this. I think his `allowBackup = true` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` is actually creating the problem. The old database file was not removed.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I've never had problems with that, always used the default true (however I generally only use emulators). Looking into that aspect now to see.